# Read it from the book

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

If a teacher asks a kid to read something aloud, will it be natural to use "from"?

> Read it **from** the book.

Is the use of "**from**" in this context common?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would a teacher need to mention "the book"?  Only because she wants to make it clear to the child that they should read from "the book", and not from the worksheet, or from the poster, or from memory (for example)

In this context it is correct to say "...from the book."

> I'd like you to begin from scene 5 please.
>   But I haven't learn my lines yet!
>   That's ok, you can read from the book.

Or to specify a particular book

> Please read from the yellow text book.

On the other hand, in most cases "from the book" is implied.  There is no need to mention it.

> I'd like you read chapter 5 please
>   ...
>   John, I'd like you to read chapter 5 *aloud* please!